# Error in Visual Studio 11:  "could not obtain license due to error 80090317"

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I have been playing around with Windows 8 Developer Preview and Visual Studio 11 Express, but I am facing an issue that is a bit annoying. Every 1 or 2 days, I get the following error when I open Visual Studio: "**could not obtain license due to error 80090317**"

[image]

This issue is mentioned [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/6398fce9-d31e-4fb4-abf2-1ddb7121e38a) and [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728710/failed-to-get-developer-license-for-visual-studio-11-beta-both-express-and-ultimate-sku-on-machines-upgraded-from-windows-7#), but in both cases it is said that the issue shows up when Windows 8 is installed as an upgrade to Windows 7, which is not my scenario. I did a clean install in an new partition and installed all the updates available. The workaround I have found so far is to put the date of my system a few months in the past, run Visual Studio and acquire a license, then put the current date back. This works for a while until the message shows up again.

**Has someone faced this issue?

Has someone a more permanent workaround for this?**

A bit more details on my current setup:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not use the Developer Preview.  Download the Windows 8 Consumer Preview and the Visual Studio 11 Beta.

Comment: Can I create Metro Style applications using that combination?

Comment: Yes.  They are the latest publicly available prerelease versions of Windows 8 and Visual Studio 11.  The Developer Preview is no longer supported.

Comment: I threw the first response as an community wiki answer; if that works for you, please mark that as the answer (I won't get rep points for it, if I read "community wiki" correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the Developer Preview. 
<s>Download the Windows 8 Consumer Preview and the Visual Studio 11 Beta</s>

**Update as for June 15, 2012:**

Download Windows 8 Release Preview and Visual Studio 2012 Release Candidate